# Argument of type 'Promise<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<T>'

Tags: react-hooks, fetch-api, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make an api call with an async function. The function is in a useEffect hook so that every time the "input" is changed by the user, it searches for a new array.

When the api function is called, it returns Promise

I though I had resolved this Promise when using async await and .then(res) ?

Here is the code:

```
export type SearchResults = {
    art_type: string
    Title: string
    Culture: string
    Nation: string
    Nationality: string
    artist_type: string
    Artist: string
    source_type: string
    Abbr: string
    Source: string
}[]

const App: NextPage = () => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('Gogh')
    const [results, setResults] = useState<SearchResults | undefined>(undefined)
    // const [errors, setErrors] = useState<Error | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async (input: string) => {
            const data: SearchResults = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/search/${input}`).then(res => {
                return res.json()
            })
            return data
        }

        const data = fetchData(input)
        setResults(data)
    }, [input])
    
    const searchHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.target !== null) setInput(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    } 

    const deboucedSearchHandler = useMemo(() => debounce(searchHandler, 500), [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by moving my fetchData declaration outside useEffect. Then I made the anon func used by .then() asynchronous and has the res.json() assigned to a variable with the await keyword.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('Gogh')
const [results, setResults] = useState<SearchResults | undefined>(undefined)
// const [errors, setErrors] = useState<Error | null>(null)

const fetchData = async (input: string) => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/search/${input}`).then(async res => {
            const response: SearchResults = await res.json()
            setResults(response)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(input)
}, [input])

const searchHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target !== null && e.target.value !== '') setInput(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
} 

const deboucedSearchHandler = useMemo(() => debounce(searchHandler, 450), [])
```